# Combine an Akka CircuitBreaker with a router

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to use a router and have the calls to it's routees be protected by the use of a CircuitBreaker so that temporarily failing actors can fail fast? Does it make sense? I guess that a custom router could put aside the open breakers, sending an occasional message to them to see if they have recovered and if so, adding them back to the usable routees, instead of simply keep failing fast for a already known open breaker.
Is there any kind of support for this scenario? Couldn't find any mention to it.

The question [detecting failure from remote nodes from an akka router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125377/detecting-failure-from-remote-nodes-from-an-akka-router) seems to be relatively close in spirit, but doesn't really address this scenario.